# assigning a pointer to anathor changes its value

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to delete a node from a linked list using the following code

```
void deleteMatchNode(node **list, int match)
{
    node **temp = list;
    node **prev = NULL;
    while (*temp != NULL)
        {
            if ((*temp)->member == match)
                {
                    printf ("match found\n");
                    break;
                }
            prev = temp;
            temp = &(*temp) ->next;
        }
    printf("gg1 %p %p\n", *temp, *prev);
    (*prev)->next = (*temp)-> next;
    printf("gg %p %p\n", *temp, *prev);
    printList(*list);
    //free(*temp);
}
```

but the assignment of (*temp)-> next to (*prev)->next is changing the value of *temp, can someone please point out the error. The printList works as expected but the list is corrupted once the free is called on *temp.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: `temp` is pointing at `list` so they're equivalent.  If you do something in one, you do it in the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the spacing in your code is misleading.

```
prev = temp;
temp = &(*temp) ->next;
```

This is the same as:

```
prev = temp;
temp = &((*temp)->next);
```

Given the previous assignment you could have writted this as:

```
temp = &((*prev)->next);
```

So `temp` points to `(*prev)->next` so naturally assigning to `(*prev)->next` changes the value of `*temp` because they are two ways of referring to the same object.

You probably want to just save a pointer to the node being removed from the list to free later:

```
Node *save = *temp;
(*prev)->next = (*temp)->next;
free(save);
```

There are a number of possiblities for `NULL` pointers that you need to check for. If the loop exits on the first iteration then `prev` will be null, if the loop exits because `*temp` is null then, naturally, `*temp` is null. You need to consider both of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand your code fully, but i think in your code:
`(*prev)->next` is equal to `*temp` because of this, when you free the temp, the linklist is broken.
i suggest you to use this:

```
void deleteMatchNode(node **list, int match)
{
    node *temp = *list;
    node *prev = NULL;
    while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->member == match)
                {
                    printf ("match found\n");
                    break;
                }
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp ->next;
        }
    printf("gg1 %p %p\n", temp, prev);
    if(temp == *list){
          *list = temp->next;
    }else{
          prev->next = temp->next;
    }
    printf("gg %p %p\n", temp, prev);
    printList(*list);

    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: You need the extra level of indirection, otherwise you can't delete the first node in the list.

Comment: The change you just made, to add `if (temp == list)...`, doesn't solve that problem. You're updating the local variable `list`, but not the caller's pointer. He'll still have a pointer to the now freed node.

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the `while` loop, `*temp` is `NULL`. Therefore, `(*temp)->next` is not a valid pointer.

Comment: Unless the loop has been exited via the `break` statement.